# recvfrom returning error when trying to read UDP datagrams

Tags: c++, windows, udp, winsock, recvfrom

I'm trying to make a very simple UDP server but I can't seem to grasp how to do it. I've looked at the Microsoft documentation but even then I ran into this problem. It seems the recvfrom function is returning an error and calling WSAGetLastError tells me it's an invalid argument error, but to me it seems like the arguments are correct:

```
int main( int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    char request[MAX_REQUEST_LEN];
    int port;
    SOCKET sock;
    bool quit = false;

    port = 11130;

    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != NO_ERROR)
    {
        cout << "WSAstartup failed" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // Create a socket.
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    if (sock == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        WSACleanup();
        cout << "Error at socket" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    sockaddr_in server, client;
    int c_len = sizeof(client);

    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    server.sin_port = htons(port);

    bind( sock, (sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server) );

    while(!quit)
    {
        memset(request,'\0', MAX_REQUEST_LEN);
        int result = recvfrom(sock, request, MAX_REQUEST_LEN, 0, (struct sockaddr*) &client, &c_len);
        cout << "Received: " << request << endl << "recvfrom return: " << result << endl;
           //process request

    }

    closesocket(sock);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked the return value of `bind()`?

Comment: It seems that the program was calling std::bind instead of the winsock bind. Removing "using namespace std" did the job. Thanks.

Comment: ::bind() would have done as well. You should still have put in some error checking for the bind() call, as you did for socket(), and as you should also have done for recvfrom().